# Apache Beam and Cloud SQL connection issue

Tags: jdbc, google-cloud-sql, apache-beam

I am trying to connect to my Google Cloud SQL instance(Postgres) via Apache beam pipeline from my local machine.
But when I run the pipeline, I get an error reading :

```
org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v20_0.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: 
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
```

I have already added my IPv4 address under authorized networks in Cloud SQL

```
pipeline.apply(JdbcIO.<KV<Integer, String>>read()
                .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
                        "org.postgresql.Driver", "jdbc:postgresql://google/<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=<POSTGRESQL_USER_NAME>&password=<POSTGRESQL_USER_PASSWORD>"))
                .withQuery("select id, name from EMPLOYEE")
                .withCoder(KvCoder.of(BigEndianIntegerCoder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of()))
                .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<KV<Integer, String>>() {
                    public KV<Integer, String> mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
                        return KV.of(resultSet.getInt(1) + 100, "Mr" + resultSet.getString(2));
                    }
                }));
```

Comment: Have you added your IP address or your network?

Comment: How are you authenticating with GCP/Cloud SQL? Are you using the Proxy? Because it might well be easier if you use the proxy and "pretend" to just connect to localhost with the Beam pipeline.